# Inserting Video into blog that exists on different web application

Tags: my-site, web-application, blog, mysite, video

Setup is SharePoint 2013, on premise. We have multiple web applications, an intranet, an extranet, and MySites.

I have been including videos resources on my Blog via a Video Library within MySite. It worked so well that management wants me to move those videos to a new "IT Department" site that is on our Intranet, but to continue to use video within my blogs.

I always desire to have only one copy of information - especially videos. Since I'm trying to embed the videos within my blog posts, just linking to the video isn't going to work. When I try to insert the video via "SharePoint", I can't get to it and if I try to insert it via address, it errors out.

Is there a way to these video resources available to MySite so I can only have one version of the video but have it as a resource to multiple locations, specifically presented inline on my Blog site, or is the only way to get this done is to maintain the two versions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the content search web part that should be able to get your videos from different web applications. There is a template for videos but you can customize your own.

Comment: That would be fine if the blog posts were web part pages, but I'm using Create a Blog and I can't insert a Content Search Web Part within the Body of the Blog Post.

Comment: if you activate publishing infrastructure in the blog (the new blog) you will have a library called pages where you can have all the pages that you want

Comment: I did find the answer on another site. Ultimately, since I'm going between collections, I need to embed the video (although both collections are mine). I had that step correct, but I was still getting an error with the embedding.
I had to go to the Top Level of MySite and go into HTML Field Security and add the addresses I was using for those other sites into the domains to allow the iframes. A good bit of clicks to copy and paste, but this works now and there is only 1 copy of the videos.